# jQuery addclass after load a file from personal function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, addclass

I have a personnal function which load a file and I want after loading the page changing a class.

The function is

```
var _loadFile = function(filename, container, errorMessage) {
    $.ajax({
        url : filename,
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        success : function (data) {
            $(container).html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

When I want to use it I do

```
_loadFile('assets/data/html/file.html', '#containerID', 'errorMessage');
$(idActive).addClass('active');
```

The file is loaded but the class is not changed. And as I want a generic function I can't change the class in the success().

Thanx for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to modify DOM (addClass) of the element that is not yet loaded. Try this approach instead:

```
var _loadFile = function(filename, container, errorMessage) {
    return $.ajax({
        url : filename,
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        success : function (data) {
            $(container).html(data);
        }
    });
}

_loadFile('assets/data/html/file.html', '#containerID', 'errorMessage')
.then(function() {
    $(idActive).addClass('active');
});
```

`$.ajax` returns promise object, and you use `then` method of it. You could also move `$(idActive).addClass('active');` inside success callback, but it's not nice: I assume that `_loadFile` is a generic function and we don't want it to be aware of anything else but loading data.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the class on the `success callback` if the element "idActive" is loaded via AJAX:

```
var _loadFile = function(filename, container, errorMessage) {
    $.ajax({
        url : filename,
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        success : function (data) {
            $(container).html(data);
            $(idActive).addClass('active');
        }
    });
}
```

assuming that `idActive` is defined and generated. Otherwise add an

```
console.log($(idActive));
```

and look at the console output to be certain, that the element you want to add the class really exists.

Comment: Thanx for your help but as I told in my question I want a generic function then I can't use addClass() into my _loadFile function